# Different width's on front and article page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, width

So i'm making this site which is based on wordpress for adding dynamic content but i have set up an entirely HTML/CSS and little jQuery built theme.

The issue i'm facing is when I had to place the front page posts like teasers with a link to the entire post

teaser like this :- http://i.gyazo.com/dda9c60eb3a822b84bdcb3e0067dfc3e.png

as i knew nothing about wordpress themes, i took help of esclate's php files and just made up a code that could harbour my css classes,id's and properties with it.

Hence to start with, the post's elements in header.php was setup like this :-

```
<div class="post-wrapper">


    <div id="page">
    <div id="page-bgtop">
        <div id="page-bgbtm">
            <div id="content">
```

that was the same for the single.php file,

i successfully made the site have teaser posts for the front page but the issue arrived when the same properties of those above ID's got called to the single.php file as the classes and id's were similar, which is shown/open when the user clicks on full article,

i made another class for the single.php post elements but it had no effects.

here is what it looked like :- http://i.gyazo.com/0ec25c1db676463dd6aea209480e9568.png

it shows a teaser and not the full post, how can i rectify this?

btw the css code for them all

```
#page {
width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;

}

#page-bgtop {
}

#page-bgbtm {
margin: 0px;
padding: 40px 50px 0px 50px;

}



#content {
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin-left: -40px;
padding: 20px;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 40px;
font-family: 'Raleway',Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 23px;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

I hope i have discreetly explained everything in my grasp for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with id's the same will be applied where-ever the id's are used, it overrides classes by default. You can create new id's or add class="" in your html so in your css you can mark elements !important to override the id content. This gets messy though so you would be better to change your ids to classes in the above example and use id's to make small changes to the class in the different pages.